# How to make dynamic arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

is it possible to make dynamic ArrayList, for an example I have

```
List<String> Group = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to have dynamic arraylist like Group1, Group2, Group3 and so on...
How do achieve this inside iteration?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     List<String> Group+i = new ArrayList<String>(); // generate group-n
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: may be `ArrayList` inside `ArrayList`?

Comment: No you cant create list of list in java. Better you use map instead or you can arrange data such that will not have list of list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically name objects in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711067/how-do-i-dynamically-name-objects-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
List<List<String>> collectionOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for(int i = 0; i < yourVar; i++){
    collectionOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

You can then have any number of array lists and use them as you will

Comment: @SilvansSolanki Yep, works fine after I changed some little bits to not use the abstract classes

Comment: yes thats the reason I asked you, because your earlier code will give you exception and it will not worked. good that you make it correct.

Comment: see my updated post, is your code can generate arraylist like my post? if it can, how I call/use group2 for an example...

Comment: Check the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711067/how-do-i-dynamically-name-objects-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list use arraylist and you can proceed ahead.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {    List<String> mylist$i   = new ArrayList<String>();}
```

it will give you

```
List<String> mylist1   = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> mylist2   = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> mylist3   = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> mylist4   = new ArrayList<String>();
```

"$" can be used to join and create a new string/variable.